# How can I bind a Mongo-Docker Container and a simple CRUD Server Container written on Nodejs on a bridge network?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a bridge network called my_network, a Mongo container, a CRUD server on Nodejs.
I push the mongo container like this:

```
docker run -dit --name my_server --network web_server -p 27023:27017 --rm mongo
```

My server I push like this:

```
docker run -dit --name my_server --network web_server -p 3000:3000 --rm serverv1
```

If I start Mongo container and then start Nodejs server locally, everything works fine, but after I push this server to a Container on my bridge Network, it is not reachable for 30s and then it stops.

I'm sure that they cannot establish a communication to each other. Server just cannot connect to my mongo. After I push them on my network it looks like this: [there two containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEag7.png)

I have tried to change PORT in my env file with server, but it is also 3000 as I define in docker.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: What is the actual error message?  What code produces the PNG file you attached to the question?  How have you configured the database location when you run the application in a container?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same --name flag (my_server) for both the MongoDB and Node.js containers. This will cause conflicts and only one of them will be running. You should use different names for each container.

Try this :

```
docker run -dit --name my_mongo --network my_network -p 27023:27017 --rm mongo

docker run -dit --name my_nodejs_server --network my_network -p 3000:3000 --rm serverv1
```

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake when I was typing here and describing a problem. In my project I have a name my_mongo and my_server, but I still have the same probplem. According to logs in Docker, Server cannot establish a connection to the db